# Read JSON file with ASYNC Task

Tags: java, json, android-studio

I am trying to read information from a JSONfile, which i shall use in my android application (I'm using android studio). It seems like the code is able to read and save the whole file, but is not able to pick out the information i want? This is the JSON file i'm trying to read from: http://www.ime.ntnu.no/api/course/tma4100. 
Can anyone tell me what i'm doing wrong?
Thankyou.

```
public class JSONTask extends AsyncTask<String,String,String> {

private Fag nyttFag;

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    BufferedReader reader = null;


    try {
        URL url = new URL(params[0]);
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.connect();

        //read from API

        InputStream stream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));


        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

        String line = "";
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            buffer.append(line);
        }

        String finalJson = buffer.toString();

        //Get objekt course from the whole API
        JSONObject parentObject = new JSONObject(finalJson);
        JSONObject course = parentObject.getJSONObject("course");

        StringBuffer finalBufferedData = new StringBuffer();
        //JSONObject finalObject = parentObject2.getJSONObject(0);
        String coursename = course.getString("name");
        String code = course.getString("code");
        System.out.println(coursename);
        finalBufferedData.append(code + "-" +  coursename + "\n");
        nyttFag = new Fag(code,coursename);

        return finalBufferedData.toString();

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (urlConnection != null) {
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
        try {
            if (reader != null) {
                reader.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    MainActivityProfessor.fagData.setText(result);
    if (!navnPåFag.contains(nyttFag.name)) {
        navnPåFag.add(nyttFag.name);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You need to certify that the JSON is being downloaded correctly, I'd suggest some debbuging on the line:

```
JSONObject parentObject = new JSONObject(finalJson);
```

Verify if the **finalJson** is correctly parsed and after that if the **course** variable is really becoming an JSONObject.